# Upload File with GWT RequestBuilder

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to do some kind of "wrapping" to allow uploading of file through RequestBuilder?

1. Pick a file using a From
2. Send the file using RequestBuilder

Something that wraps something similar like this:

```
<input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload">
var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
  var name = "photo.jpg";

  var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
}
```

In my case what I need is to be able to get the pass the `file` and `name` to RequestBuilder to do the upload / POST.

Can this be done? Or there's a better way to do this? 
What I need is to have something like this:

```
public void upload(JavascriptObject file, String name, AsyncCallback<String> callback){
// Here goes the actual uploading (probably using RequestBuilder) then trigger callback
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a RequestBuilder? What is wrong with the GWT FileUpload widget and an ordinary Servlet on the server side handling the file contents?

Comment: This is for API integration